# AWS get cost by specific users

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to see the spendings on my company's AWS account monthly, by specific users.
So far I am only able to see the spendings monthly by service.
This can be done using AWS Cost explorer.
AWS Cloudtrail allows me to see any user activity.
Is there any way to combine these two services to reach my goal?
Or would it be done another way?

Comment: you can write python or other script using aws sdk or boto3 library to get data and then analyse cost.

Comment: Thanks @aviboy2006 , is there any example online you might direct me to?

Comment: AWS CLI : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html and Python boto3 : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html

Comment: added one sample code also @GustavRasmussen

Comment: Does that really give you the information you want? Because you're asking for per-user costs, but that report shows per-service/account costs.

Comment: To actually get per-user costs, you need to require users to tag the resources that they create.

Comment: Thank you @Parsifal, this information helps me to now fully get the picture of cost by users. The resource-tagging was the final step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write custom script using language AWS SDK support.
I will suggest python using `boto3`

AWS CLI : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html and

Python boto3 : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html

This is one of developer has done this. You can use as reference :
https://github.com/hjacobs/aws-cost-and-usage-report